# How can I reduce the time it takes to resolve http to https?

Tags: css, wordpress, performance, https, http-headers

I'm trying to increase the page speed of one of my wordpress websites.

I know I can still combine some css files, but the majority of the loading time is taken up by requesting the headers for the http version of my site (2.07s). After which it continues to get the header for the https version of the site(1.1), after which it loads the site.

https://gtmetrix.com/reports/ohiobear.com/wcvaHH5v

For the http version it gives a 301 moved permanently status code.

Is there a correct way to make this go faster?

Answer (score 0):

http to https redirection changes made in index.php or in .htaccess, 
if in index.php then do the changes inside .htaccess